# Some extension for connectedness

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $X $ be a quasi compact topological space and $Y $ be a subspace of $X $.  I am looking for some topological properties  on $Y $  such that if $Y $ is a connected subspace of $X $, then $Y $ has these properties, that is , I am looking for some extensions for the concept of the connectedness.

Comment: Any space is a subspace of a quasi compact space, so there are no such properties beyond the ones already implied by connectedness

Comment: @Max Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost : I was not entirely certain that that was what the OP asked for, I was waiting for perhaps a clarification